# Can I build a MacOS version of my app that will run on anything earlier than 10.15 using Xcode11?

Tags: xcode, macos

Can't find a definitive answer to this question: I am using Xcode 11 on MacOS 10.15 (Catalina). I can build a MacOS version for a 10.15 deployment target. But many of my beta testers aren't yet on 10.15. Is it possible to build for earlier versions. I tried changing the Build Settings>MacOS Deployment target to 10.6 and archived and notarized the app, but when I try to run on 10.12 Mac I get "You have macOS 1012. This application requires macOS 10.15 or later"

It seems like there are other posts from earlier versions of Xcode indicating devs have built for earlier versions. Can only one help with a recipe or a definitive answer?

Comment: Did you change the build setting on the target or the project? The setting on the target (if set) can override the one on the project.

Comment: I set it for the Target and the resolved version correctly shows 10.6 (or now 10.9)

Comment: The message you cite is because of the `LSMinimumSystemVersion` key in the app's Info.plist. I believe that Xcode's template projects reference the deployment target build setting for that key, so it is automatically consistent. However, if you've manually set that key to something else, that connection is broken. What is the value for that key in your built app's Info.plist? Also, what's the output from `otool -lV /path/to/YourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/YourApp | grep -A3 LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was a fundamental misunderstanding on my part of how Xcode 11 worked with a universal target of iOS/iPad/MacOS. That is new in Xcode 11 and only works with MacOS 10.15.

Once I created a NEW target just for MacOS, I was able to select older versions of MacOS back to 10.9. So Xcode 11 works just fine.