# How to set the Mac App Store 'Compatibility' to an older version of macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos

In Xcode Version 11.6 (11E708) on 10.15.6, I've tried setting my project Deployment Target to 10.12 (Sierra), and also setting the Deployment Target in the app target itself to 10.12 (apparently the latter takes priority). When I do this, the binary produced by the build process successfully runs on my test Mac (running Sierra). However, when this same binary appears on the Mac App Store, the compatibility is: 'macOS 10.15 or later, 64-bit processor'.

As suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61450630/can-i-build-a-macos-version-of-my-app-that-will-run-on-anything-earlier-than-10), I've run:

```
otool -lV '~/Desktop/Baker Street 2020-08-24 15-07-26/Baker Street.app/Contents/MacOS/Baker Street' | grep -A3 LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
```

I get the following output:

```
cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
cmdsize 16
version 10.12
sdk 10.15.6
```

This is expected - i.e. the minimum version appears to be set correctly. What's happening between this and the App Store that switches the minimum version up to 10.15? Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is now working! It might well have been some kind of caching issue. I'll leave the question as-is, so my steps are clear - if you follow these, you should (eventually) have an app in the store that honours the minimum version set in Xcode.